# Competing risk model for time dependent variable-longitudinal dataset in R

Tags: r, cox-regression

I have a longitudinal dataset looks like this:

| id | tstart | tstop | age | sex | exposure | event | some time-varying covariates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 12 | 18 | 1 | 0 | 0 | Not shown here |
| 1 | 12 | 36 | 21 | 1 | 0 | 0 | Not shown here |
| 2 | 0 | 10 | 25 | 2 | 1 | 0 | Not shown here |
| 2 | 10 | 18 | 26 | 2 | 1 | 0 | Not shown here |
| 2 | 18 | 27 | 27 | 2 | 1 | 1 | Not shown here |
| 3 | 0 | 15 | 30 | 2 | 1 | 0 | Not shown here |
| 3 | 15 | 29 | 32 | 2 | 1 | 0 | Not shown here |
| 3 | 29 | 37 | 34 | 2 | 1 | 2 | Not shown here |

I would like to do a competing risk model, but I found crr() function only allows including an interaction between a continuous variable and the function of time. Is there any function like coxph(tstart, tstop, event)-the start-stop format that I can use to do the competing risk model?
Does anyone know it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Perhaps [compete](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf) from `survival` package offers what you're looking for.

Comment: @Chris, thank you for your comments. When I used finegray() based on the dataset shown above:  df$event <- factor(df$event, 0:2, labels=c("censor", "cvd", "cancer")); df.w <-finegray(Surv(tstart, tstop, event) ~ cov1+cov2+cov3, data=df, etype='cvd', id="id"); and then error occurred 'Error in model.frame.default(formula = Surv(tstart, tstop, event) ~  : Variables  ('(id)') have different lengths. I don't know how to deal with it. hope for your help; thank you!